# Android studio not showing ''sync now'' option after adding some dependencies

Tags: java, android-studio

when I add some whatever dependencie in the Gradle file then android studio should show the sync now option but it's not showing.
Android Studio Version 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select "Sync Project with Gradle Files" from the top right bar manually.